# Can dogs get Campylobacter infection from humans?

Tags: dogs, infections

My dog possibly has a Campylobacter infection (unsure at this point, her stool is been tested) but is been treated for it with antibiotics. Problem is is that it is the second time in a month she has got it.

So I was just wondering if it was possible for her to have picked it up from some kids she sometimes spends time with that I know do not wash thier hands after going to the toilet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camplyobactor is usually found in chicken or poultry. Particularly if it has not been cooked well enough.

It's unlikely to have been transferred from the humans to the dog, it's more likely to be transferred in the opposite direction. It's most likely coming from something the dog is eating or drinking.

> [**How Campylobacter infection is spread**](http://www.sahealth.sa.gov.au/wps/wcm/connect/public+content/sa+health+internet/health+topics/health+conditions+prevention+and+treatment/infectious+diseases/campylobacter+infection)
>
> Eating contaminated food is the most frequent cause of this infection.
>   Campylobacter is commonly found in raw or undercooked poultry meat.
>   Occassionally other sources of infection include:
>
> - infected individuals, particularly infants
> - household pets, especially puppies and kittens
> - domestic stock
> - raw milk
> - contaminated water.

Check all her food and water sources and if she has access to any garbage, or carrion, and don't give her raw poultry that is past it's used by date.

Comment: It's a nasty illness. I've been hospitalised twice for it - both times from eating chicken that wasn't cooked properly.